# What happens to Awakening Values after transferring Pokémon into Home?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-lets-go, pokemon-home

Pokémon Let’s Go has Awakening Values (AVs), which was this games version of Effort Values (EVs). AVs worked similar in nature to EVs, but worked differently as to how to obtain them and had different maximum thresholds.

I have a few Pokémon in Let’s Go that I put a lot of time into increasing their AVs through the use of candy, and maxed out their stats. If I were to move these Pokémon into Pokémon Home, and then move them into Pokémon Sword, what would happen to the AVs?

Would the AVs completely go away and the Pokémon’s EVs are set to 0, or would the AVs be somehow translated into the EV equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/78415953) on gameFAQs, it was confirmed that AVs are *not* translated, so the resulting Pokémon Home Pokémon will have 0 EVs:

> Let's Go didn't have EVs, so any Pokemon transferred from those games will have 0 EVs. A blank slate.

It's not clear whether transferring them *back* to Let's Go would retain the AV's or not, though.  (It is possible to transfer them back, so long as they only go between Let's Go and Home and don't enter Sword and Shield.)